# Website works great in everything but IE7,

Tags: css, web, internet-explorer-7

I can't seem to figure out why my website breaks in IE7, I'm sure it has to do with something in the CSS but I can't find it and its driving me nuts. I feel I've been looking at artwork so long I can't see what the problem is. Can anyone come in with a fresh set of eyes and help? Thank you =)

website: [rburtonart.com](http://www.rburtonart.com)

Comment: Can you explain in detail what the problem is? Have you tried IE8 compatibility mode? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: Works just fine in IE6 if thats any consolation!

Comment: Here what I'll do is I'll post a screen shot of what it looks like in IE7. James could you do me a favor and post a screen shot of it in IE6? Give me about 10 min and I will have a link up

Comment: Here are shots of my website http://rburtonart.com/browers.jpg with IE7, IE8, chrome 2, Safari 4, FF 3.5.3. As you can see in IE 7 the nav, mid section and the footer are messed up.

Comment: Here is a link to the CSS http://rburtonart.com/css/finerstyle.css

Comment: Finerstyle.css is W3C Valid: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frburtonart.com%2Fcss%2Ffinerstyle.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en

styleC.css is W3C Valid: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Frburtonart.com%2Fcss%2FstyleC.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=1&lang=en

Comment: I've editing my answer to include code which I *think* will fix it.

Comment: fyi, http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/ is always is a good starting point for lists

Comment: I have to get my rep up I want to give out points for everyone's help, great tip ckarbass, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I can't identify the problem, but if you've got a problem with Internet Explorer (and who doesn't?), then [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) are your friend!

They let you add code that only active in IE, or a specific IE version.  Sample:

```
<!--[if IE]>
alternate style or stylepage for broken IE implemention of CSS
<![endif]-->


<!--[if IE 7]>
Fix for something broken only in IE7, not any other version.
<![endif]-->
```

Both of these will do nothing in any other browser -- they become just another harmless comment.  If you're feeling hate towards those pesky IE6 users, you can target them for a nag to upgrade (either to another browser, or a more recent version).

---

**EDIT: found it**
Before IE8, IE had issues with floats and layout.  I *think* this will work, since I used something similar under similar circumstances.

You need to add a conditional comment containing a blcok-levelelement to FORCE the #content DIV below the header DIV. This should be empty, and force everything below it.
Try adding the following between the end of the header div, and the  declaration (line 79).  If you see too much space between the header and content, you can tinker with it.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<div style="clear: both; width: 100%; padding:0; margin:0; height:1px;">&nbsp;</div> 
<!-- Fix for IE box model issues with content div -->
</div>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Would that be a browser redirect script?

Comment: Uh, it could be if you wanted it to be.  Modifications to styles, additional stylesheets, or some additional javascript are more common. That line of text: anything you want can go there, as many lines as you want.  It'll be uncommented if the browser matches the if-condition.  
------
The beautiful irony: the conditional comments feature was supposed to be a extra bonus feature for IE, to encourage its use. Instead it is used to quickly hack in IE support for something that won't work with it because IE has crappy CSS support.

Comment: Hahaha love it. I think its come down to something is wrong in my CSS. What that might be I have no idea. I did some cleaning using W3C but its still coming out messed up. http://rburtonart.com/browers.jpg

Comment: That looks *just* like a problem with the CSS box model, one infamous class of the infamous bugs present in IE.  I've seen this sort of thing before, and it's tricky to debug. IE8 will handle it OK in standards mode, so that's why it rendered fine there, just as with non-IE browsers.  IE6 probably is so broken it ignores chunks of styles altogether, including the parts responsible.  I'll go diving in the styles tomorrow when I've got time; just remember it's good etiquette here to reward good answers with up-votes and accept the best one eventually (this gives you reputation too).

Comment: Ah thank you Bob didn't know. I'm new to the site so I'm trying to feel out how everything works. Also think you for taking the time out to help. If we can come to a conclusion I'm be more then gladly to check this.

Comment: Bob that fix worked excepted it pushed the content all the way down (huge gap). I tried to say height:0px just to see what it would do and it didn't change the height of the gap.

Comment: Something told me to check this in Safari 4. Its doing the same thing that IE7 is doing with the gap. If you don't have IE 7 installed and want to see this gap check it in Safari 4

Comment: chrome 2 does it as well but IE 8 and FF 3.5.3 are fine with it.

Comment: Something in styles is altering the height or margins/borders/etc of that block level element -- uncomment it, and use the Firefox Web Developer plugin to identify which styles apply to it.  It's also possible the non-breaking space somehow has a HUGE font size.

Comment: I took the comment out "<!-- Fix for IE box model issues with content div -->" and that fixed the spacing issue with Chrome and Safari but IE 7 still has that huge gap. I agree it has to do with something with the CSS but I'm still trying to figure out what is causing it.

Comment: Bob I've tried to tinker with the code you gave me some more, if I make the height lets say 2000px for testing that works and effects the page. Now if I say 0px it looks like there is a 500px gap no matter what. What could be causing this gap?

Comment: It might be another style that you wouldn't have expected -- or padding/border/margin on another item?

Comment: +1 for the really helpful answer to a not at all helpful question

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what's broken and I don't have IE7 handy, but for starters your site doesn't validate, either as XHTML Strict (your nominated doctype) or for the CSS. I would be fixing the validation errors before doing anything else.

Comment: Web Developer extension for Firefox (get it along with Firebug if you haven't already) which in turn uses the W3C standard validators.

Comment: da5id, what could be the problem with IE 7 that it can't render <ul id="menu"> correct like the other browers?

http://rburtonart.com/browers.jpg

Answer (score 1):

your menu en footer li needs

`float: left;`

your center piece bugs on the height of the flash....

i guess you need to take a closer look at that.

IE now comes with a handy developer tool in which you can change the css on the fly.

Comment: Here is the top menu CSS code

#menu {
 padding: 0; 
 margin: 0; 
 list-style: none; 
 height: 27px; 
 position: relative;
 z-index: 500;
 }
 
#menu li {
 margin-right: 0;
 text-align: center; 
 }
 
#menu li a {
 display: block; 
 float: left; 
 height: 27px; 
 line-height: 20px;
 color: #fff; 
 text-decoration: none;
 outline: none;
 font-family: Verdana,Geneva,Kalimati,sans-serif;
 word-spacing: 0.15em;
 font-size: .8em;
 padding: 0 0 0 0;
 }

In the #menu li a { you can see the "float: left;" 

if I put it in #menu { it messes the whole menu up (options start staking ontop of each other)

Comment: Also the flash movie is is 880 X 405 and its the same with the css

#flashholder {
 width: 880px;
 height: 405px;
 background: #121212;
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
 float: left; 
 }

Comment: I think Kennethvr is right, #menu li needs float:left; added to it
#menu li { margin-right: 0; text-align: center; float:left; }

Comment: You are correct ckarbass, Kennethvr is right. I tried it on my end and it fixed the top and footer menu in IE7. Now the only issues that remain are why the flash area (div "flashholder") and the content area (div "main") are overlapping each other. The answer from this would not only fix this issue but also fix the over lapping issue on the current work link and other artwork link. Also THANK YOU BOTH, this is so close of being fixed and I couldn't do it without everyone who has replied!

Answer (score 0):

give your body

`background-color: #353535`

change the min-height of the wrap to for example

`min-height: 650px`

and change the #main bottom padding to for example

`padding-bottom: 20px`

this should solve your problem! it does in my browsers!

Comment: Heres the issue, I'm using a sticky footer (http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html) so the styleC.css that has 

html, body, #wrap {height: 100%;}

body > #wrap {
  height: auto; 
  min-height: 100%;
  background: #353535;
  }

that min-height has to stay 100% if not it moves the footer up and leaves a gap at the bottom.

Comment: I believe this is not a superb way to set a footer that sticks to the bottom.

why don't you set a footer:
position: fixed
bottom: 0;

take a look at a website like this:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

sticky footer displays the issues on the homepage, that's not a good way to start, is it?

Comment: Thank you for replying Kennethvr, I'll give this a shot tomorrow and see what I can come up with. This method looks like it will work =) Thank you for looking out!

Comment: Ok after looking at Matthews example and going back to mine, the footer stays at the bottom in IE7. The only issue is the LARGE gap between the top content and the bottom as you can see on the homepage. Once this issue is out of the way this can be applied to the rest of the site.